# possible to do an on location reload and then trigger click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click, reload

I would like to do a click function with a location reload and then trigger a click function is this possible?

code example below;

```
  $('.ui-button').click(function () {
           location.reload();
           $('#Sites').trigger('click');

        });
```

Comment: First of all your code provided is not what you tried as two closing braces where as one opening braces. Provide full code or demo so that one can help you.

Comment: just an error i will edit.

Answer (score 0):

U have to have 2 event listeners, one which trigger click on reload and second which reload page on .ui-button click..

By this code sample you just after click reload the page, but script stop because of reload..

I dont know, what kind of action u've done and why u need reload, but isnt better AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a hash to your url and then reloading.

```
$('.ui-button').click(function () {
          location.hash="cs";
          location.reload();
 });
```

Once loaded with the hash, auto-click your `#sites`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.hash=="#cs"){
        $('#Sites').trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Add the above functions to your code.